# Python Object in Dictionary Key Error

Tags: python, dictionary

Im attempting to write a chess 'Swiss' tournament manager in Python. I have two classes, a match class and a player class. I also have two dictionaries, name_object, which binds a string name to an object, and name_score, which binds the Player object's name to the Player object's score (1.0, 2.5 etc.).

Variable Example

```
    name_object = {'Jim' : Object, 'Jack' : Object}
    name_score = {'Jim': 2.5, 'Jack' : 1.0}
```

My Classes

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, gender, rating, score):
    self.name = name
    self.gender = gender
    self.rating = rating
    self.score = score

class Match:
    def __init__(self, white, black):
        self.white = white
        self.black = black

    def Result(self, res):
        global name_object, name_score
        complete = False
        if res == 1:
            if complete == False:
                name_object[self.white].score += 1
                name_score[self.white] += 1
                complete = True
        elif res == 0:
            if complete == False:
                name_object[self.black].score += 1
                name_score[self.black].score += 1
                complete = True
        elif res == 'd':
            if complete == False:
                name_object[self.white].score += .5
                name_score[self.white] += .5
                name_object[self.black].score += .5
                name_score[self.black].score += .5
```

but when I try to create an object with the two player names of 'Jim' and 'Jack',

```
    Match1 = Match(name_object['Jim'], name_object['Jack'])
```

and then try to call the Result method with white winning,

```
    Match1.Result(1)
```

I get this error,

```
    line 43, in Result
    name_object[self.white].score += 1
    KeyError: <__main__.Player object at 0x02AB6DF0>
```

All help is much appreciated

Comment: why do you need/want globals?

Comment: globals are in indicator of does-not-know-better.

Comment: because I need to use name_object and name_score in other functions

Comment: In this case: you use pdb to figure out what name_object contains as keys and compare it to the key you are trying to use to access the dict.

Comment: There is zero need to define module-level dicts as globals.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, could I have an example to make things clearer

Comment: Take 'pdb'. I am not debugging your code.

Comment: I guess you should use 'self.white.name' instead of 'self.white'. self.white is Class Player's instance, but your global dic's key is string.

Comment: I tried this, name_object[self.white].name.score += 1, but I still get the KeyError with the memory address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.white` is set to `name_object['Jim']`, so when you do `name_object[self.white]` you are in effect searching the dict like

```
name_object[name_object['Jim']]
```

I very much doubt that that makes sense. You might want to consider passing `'Jim'` alone in as `self.white` and then using `name_object[self.white]` in the rest of your code as appropriate.

Comment: At what point in the code is self.white set to name_object['Jim'], is it when name_object[self.white].score += 1 is executed

Comment: It's back when you do `Match(name_object['Jim'], name_object['Jack'])` and then `self.white = white`.

Comment: Hey, after a while, I fixed this problem. Your answer was very helpful, and allowed me to further enhance my program. Thanks very much, Johnny.

Answer (score 0):

By eyeball, your `name_object` dict has strings for keys (`'Jim'` and `'Jack'`).  But your

```
name_object[self.white].score += 1
```

line (the one Python is complaining about) is not using a string to index `name_object`.  It's using `name_object['Jim']` (which is the undefined-in-the-code-you've-shown `Object`) to index that dict.  That's why you're getting the `KeyError`:  you're trying to index the dict using a key that's not in the dict.

How you fix it is up to you.  I can't guess whether you **want** to use strings or instances of `Player` to index your dict.